# combobox with values from multiply tables mathematical operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

With little help some of you I have created this:

```
 spojeni.Open();
 var cb4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cena1,cena2,cena3,tcena1,tcena2,tcena3 FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+zakce.Text,spojeni);

 SqlDataReader dr4 = cb4.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr4.Read())

            {
                string val1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena1"]);
                string val2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena2"]);
                string val3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena3"]);
                string tval1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena1"]);
                string tval2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena2"]);
                string tval3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena3"]);
                comboBox4.Items.Add(val1 + " -- " + tval1);
                comboBox4.Items.Add(val2 + " -- " + tval2);
                comboBox4.Items.Add(val3 + " -- " + tval3);

            }
            dr4.Close();
            dr4.Dispose();

            spojeni.Close();
```

Now to make my question more clear. val1,val2,va3 are `numeric(9.2)` values and tcena1,tcena2,tcena3 are `char(10)` . I have `textbox1` in which I insert number like 4 or whatever. And I would like it to pick from val1,val2,val3 depending on what value of those was `SelectedItem` in `comboBox4`. To multiply selected value from `comboBox4` with `textBox1` value.

The final value will be displayed in `textBox2`. 
So I wanted to ask you how can I pick the `numeric(9,2)` value from val1,val2 or val3 depending on what item was selected in `comboBox4` and multiply that ? Thanks in advance

How should we improve it ? Thanks in advance.

```
 try
        {

          //  textBox19.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(comboBox4.SelectedValue) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text.Trim())).ToString();
            if (comboBox4.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                int textboxValue = 0;
                double comboxValue = 0;
                if (double.TryParse(comboBox4.SelectedValue.ToString(), out comboxValue) && int.TryParse(textBox16.Text.Trim(), out textboxValue))
                {
                    textBox19.Text = (comboxValue * textboxValue).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Chybové hlášení2: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You are looking for something like this. textbox2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedValue) * Convert.ToInt32(text1.Text.Trim()).

Comment: @EhsanUllah Thank you so much for your code, but it says this: "Cannot implicitly convert type double to string "

Comment: See my answer for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for something like this.

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
{
    int textboxValue = 0;
    double comboxValue = 0;
     if(double.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),out comboxValue) && int.TryParse(text1.Text.Trim(),out textboxValue))

      {
        textbox2.Text = (comboxValue * textboxValue).ToString();
      }
```

}

Comment: Hello thanks again so much, but it says "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands 'double' and 'string' . How Should I change it ?

Comment: Copy it exactly you are missing some bracket. Show me the code you have written.

Comment: I did but I think you are missing them I added one which was missing, see the answer. Thanks again. As I coped exactly It said one bracket was missing so I added it .

Comment: Your bracket is misplaced. I have updated mine though. Mark it as answer.

Comment: How can I mark it if it still gives an error? Other users will be confused. Its giving  "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands 'double' and 'string'

Comment: -1 because It didnt worked for querist and You werent able to solve problém which came up With Your solution

Comment: @MarekŠíp you missed my comment "Your bracket is misplaced. I have updated mine though". Check his answer his bracket is still misplaced. You should check yourself before downvoting.

Comment: Hello, it says this: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: it could be because of multiple reasons like comboBox1.SelectedValue is null or text1.Text is a non valid integer or an emtpy string. That is why i said this isn't the best code.

Comment: comboBox4.SelectedValue isnt null, but the selected value is like this: "8946.00 -- Dětská" And I need to select only the "8946.00" then multiply that with textbox1

Comment: I uploaded image so you can see clearly, I placed it into textBox1 textchanged and I get result 0, How is that possible ?

Comment: will it always contain -- chracters in selected value? I have updated my code with some error checking.

Comment: Accept my appologize Please.

Comment: @Ehsan yes it wil contain those characters. but i will try it without them

Comment: @Ehsan, Im getting still the same result - 0

Comment: Even if I insert only numeric numbers it still gives 0

Comment: I have tried your new code but it gives 2 errors: The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid arguments and 2)  cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: yeah i missed ToString(). Actually i don't have VS here. Just typing in the box above. Updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping but the textBox2 stayes empty now :o I also posted what have I inserted into VS

Comment: i guess you mean textbox19. You know how to debug. Check the values of comboxvalue and textboxvalue in the vs debugger and you will know why you are getting 0 as answer.

Comment: Ok, is it allright to put this code into private void comboBox4_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { ?

Comment: Yes, if you want the value to be recalculated everytime combobox value is updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33792/discussion-between-blaze-m-and-ehsan-ullah)

Comment: @Ehsan have you got free time so I can discuss something with you please? I hope I'm not interrupting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759170/math-operation-with-datagridview-columns-row-by-row-then-display-final-value-in