# Math operation with dataGridView columns row by row then display final value in textBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I've been thinking about what is the best way to do my datagridview math. I have this datagridview which I need to go row by row multiplying column "castka" with počet" and then + the next row then + next row until Im on the end and then display the final value in textBox.  As I'm beginner in c# and sql I wanted to discuss this with you for first. (codes are welcome  :) )

thank you so much.

This is how my table looks like.

Would someone recommend me something please?

[image]

```
 void calculateProductTwoColumns(int castkaIndex, int pocetIndex)
    {
        double[] outVals = new double[tot_rows + 1]; //Array including product of both columns per row
        int curRow = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_ksluzby.Rows)
        {
            curRow = curRow + 1;
            outVals[curRow] = (double)row.Cells[4].Value * (double)row.Cells[6].Value;
          //  MessageBox.Show(""+ outVals.ToString());
            kpriplac.Text = outVals.ToString();
        }

    }
```

this is how I call it on form_load

```
 calculateProductTwoColumns( 4, 6);
```

Comment: For discussion as you wish and for code is StackOverflow not the right page. StackOverflow wants to have questions which are helpful for future users. So basically you should ask a more like how to map a GridView with a TextEdit or something like that. You should also add what you have tried and where you have failed. By the way if would be also helpful if the screenshot is English I don't know what priplaty means.

Comment: @rekire Hello, thank you so much for your feedback, I thought that its quiet simple to describe. I just wanted to ask all of you what would be the best way to done that. I think that its not even important know what "priplatky" means because its a textBox. Would "foreach" command useful for this? I searched through the internet first, I wouldn't be asking if I had found any helpful guide on the internet. But I do ask because I have no idea where should I start. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` is a control for data-displaying purposes; if you want to perform any kind of mathematical operation you would have to create an algorithm to retrieve the data and carry out the calculations. If you are getting the data from a DB, it would be quicker to perform the operations by relying on queries. Iterating through the cells is not too difficult, neither writing to a `TextBox`; here you have a sample function performing both actions (between `dataGridView1` and `textBox1`):

```
private void calculateSumColumn(int curColumn)
{
    double valueCurColumn = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
         valueCurColumn = valueCurColumn + (double)row.Cells[curColumn].Value;
    }

    textBox1.Text = valueCurColumn.ToString();
}
```

Applied to your specific case:

```
private void calculateProductTwoColumns(int castkaIndex, int pocetIndex, int tot_rows)
{
    double[] outVals = new double[tot_rows + 1]; //Array including product of both columns per row
    int curRow = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
         curRow = curRow + 1;
         outVals[curRow] = (double)row.Cells[castkaIndex].Value * (double)row.Cells[pocetIndex].Value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, first of all I would like to thank you so much for your answer. I tried your code and as I'm begginer in c# I'm not sure if I should change (curColumn) or valueCurColumn variables to the name of my column (pocet and castka)? And may I ask also where the castka (column)* pocet(column) is happening ? Thank sou so much again.

Comment: @BlazeM the code does not refer to column names but to column indices. I have updated my code and included a function performing the exact operation you want (I am storing the products per row in an array, if you want to add all the values, just include this operation). Nonetheless, bear in mind the comment from rekire: this is not a site delivering custom algorithms but solutions helping you (and others) to grow as a developer; my first answer should have been enough to illustrate the point properly.

Comment: Ok I'm going to keep that on mind. Sorry for my behaviour. Thank you so much for your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for my trivial question, but Im in c# for 20 days, I'm not sure how to deal with "tot_rows" I believe its array as you have written. I havent used array yet, how should I improv your code??

Comment: @BlazeM tot_rows is the total number of rows and is used in my code to dimension the array, which is outVals. In principle, this variable seems to have to be treated globally and that's why I didn't declare it. I have updated my code right now such that you can pass this value as an argument. Sorry to say but just 20 days with C# sounds OK for not knowing how to deal with a DataGridView, but not even understanding what an array is, sounds like you need to learn a lot. Please understand my point (cannot work for you or deliver full working codes) and intend to keep working by your own.

Comment: @BlazeM I have seen your updated answer and I am afraid that you are not understanding the point properly: an array is used to stored many values (a way to emulate a 1-column table with as many rows as its maximimum dimension); the reason why I included it is because I don't know what you want to do with the values resulting after multiplying the two columns in each row. In your code, I see that you write the multiplication of each row to the textbox, it that case, you don't need the array. Also you are hardcoding the column indices and thus you can also delete int castkaIndex, int pocetIndex

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me. Last qeustion I promise. What if the "tot_rows" is variable, because dtg_ksluzby (the datagridview) loads data from SQL DB so I don't know how much rows will be displayed. How should tot_rows look like ? when I call it on form load?

Comment: @BlazeM lastly bear in mind that if you write the value per row to the textbox, each new value will over-write the previous one. For example: row 1 -> textbox = 5 * 3 = 15; row 2 -> textbox = 6 * 4 = 24, etc. That's why I created the array, to store all the values for all the rows as far as the textbox can only hold 1 value. You might do it multiline (and write & Environment.NewLine after each new writing), but I am not sure that this is what you want either. As you can see many problems deriving from your not-so-good knowledge. Do the best thing for you: learn C# better.

Comment: @BlazeM right after it is populated             dataGridView1.Rows.Count; and please stop asking and understand that your problem is much deeper that just solving this small problem: you have serious C# programming lacks, which you should address in a better way rather than keep asking for help to solve small problems. I will not answer any other question, I hope that you will understand my position.